# calling specific column using an interval

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

I have a data frame which contains many columns.
I want to create a new data frame which contains only some of the columns, so I've used `subset` which works great.

```
newDF<-subset(oldDF, col1==1)
```

To complicate things-- I want that one of the columns in the subset will be identified using an interval, such as `X`.
For example, I want the new dataFrame to contain all rows from the `oldDF` in which the values of `Col2Name` are bigger than zero

```
X <- "colName2"
newDF<-subset(oldDF, X>0)
```

the problem is that when I run this using `X`, I get nothing.

When I run this using the specific column name (and not an interval)

```
newDF<-subset(oldDF, colName2>0)
```

I get the right results.

when I test the value in X using oldDF[,X] I get the right column.

What am I missing? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way:

```
newdf <- olddf[(olddf$colName2 > 0),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided data I am using `mtcars` dataset as an example. When you use  :

```
subset(mtcars, cyl == 4)
```

R is looking for column named `cyl` in `mtcars`. Now when you do :

```
X <- "cyl" 
subset(mtcars, X == 4)
```

R will here look for column named `X` in `mtcars` which obviously is not present and hence it gives an empty dataframe.

There are certain ways in which you can subset a dataframe passing a variable and using `subset` is not one of them. You'll also notice that `mtcars$cyl` works fine but `mtcars$X` will not work for the same reason.

When you want to subset a dataframe using a variable you can use (as you have already figured out) `mtcars[, X]` or also `mtcars[[X]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! this is what I thought. Though I can't figure out how to use it to subset with a condition? mtcars[ , X>0]  doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @Neta Use `mtcars[mtcars[[X]] > 0, ]`